# How to let an agent identify another agent it is linked with and access its attributes

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a private transport model where a vehicle owner hires a vehicle and the driver (operator) brings back the hire fee in the evening and receives a commission.

**I am having problems letting the Operator recognise the vehicle owner they are linked with**.

while trying to set a fee the operator can charge passengers, which is dependent on the hire fee, it returns an error and reports a list instead of a vehicle owner they are linked with (the code is checked correct, but the error is returned on running the model).

```
to find-Veh-Owner
  
  let potential-Veh-Owners (Veh-Owners in-radius 5) with [NOT any? link-neighbors]  
  ifelse any? potential-Veh-Owners  [
    let target-Veh-Owner max-one-of potential-Veh-Owners [commission]
    create-link-with target-Veh-Owner
    set remittance [target-fee] of target-Veh-Owner    
    set Operator-costs one-of (range 0.3 0.4 0.05)* [target-fee] of target-Veh-Owner
    set color red
      set label "job"] [set label "Jobless" set color green]

to fix-fare-price
  
  let estimated-pax-per-day one-of (range 90 180 15)
  let target-Veh-Owner out-link-neighbors
  **set fare-price ([target-fee] of target-Veh-Owner + Operator-costs)/ estimated-pax-per-day** 
;; brings an ;;error that it expected a number and instead got a list!
end
```

Comment: Hi, please check the help page for how to ask a good question ([especially here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and with particular regard to providing a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and format the code in your question in a way that it is readable. Thanks!

Comment: you should iterate through the target-Veh-Owner list and calculate the fare-price for each owner individually

Comment: Thank you @desertnaut. However, the (+) operation attracts an error that it gets a list instead of an agentset. I created a local variable to read the [target-fee] of target-veh-owner, and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, it is hard to diagnose the problem given the unformatted code in your question, but I think the problem lies in

```
let target-Veh-Owner out-link-neighbors
```

`out-link-neighbors` returns an agentset, even if there is only one out-link.  Therefore `[target-fee] of target-Veh-Owner` returns a list of target-fees, even if the agentset has only a single member and the resulting list has only one element.

If there is only one out-link, then a simple solution would be to

```
let target-Veh-Owner one-of out-link-neighbors
```

`Target-Veh-Owner` will then be a single agent and `of` will return a single value and not a list.